# footnote + bibliography with texmaker(OSX), biber, bib latex

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, biber

Problems:

1. footnotes are not filed with info from *.bib instead only the cite key is shown
2. no bibliography shown

I use texmaker on iOS with The MacTeX-2014 Distribution.

quick build: LaTeX + Bib(la)tex + LaTeX (2x) + dvips + ps2pdf + viewpdf
As bib file I use the example bib delivered with biblatex

[image: texmaker pref. config.]

Here my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,%
    style=verbose-ibid%
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\autocite{aristotle:rhetoric}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What I noticed, that no *.bbl is being created.

I don't know how to fix this am trying for days reading through manuals and stack exchange but I'm stuck here...

**Solution to my problem:**
I changed it "/usr/texbin/biber" to "/usr/texbin/biber" %.bcf in the texmaker preferences

Comment: Did you actually run Biber?

Comment: I think yes. Its in /usr/texbin/biber and this is triggered with the quick build. I'm not sure if the order (LaTeX + Bib(la)tex + LaTeX (2x) + dvips + ps2pdf + viewpdf) is correct

Comment: can you try from the command line? It might be that the biber cache is corrupted, and then effectively you cannot run biber

Comment: OK, it that case are there any errors shown in the `.blg` file?

Comment: I did this in terminal: 

biber /Users/air/SkyDrive/Thesis/latex/not so bad/mwe_main.tex


answere:

INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is '/Users/air/SkyDrive/Thesis/latex/not.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find control file '/Users/air/SkyDrive/Thesis/latex/not.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

Comment: sorry how do i make a line break in comments for better readability?

Comment: move to the directly where the `mwe_main.tex` file and then run `pdflatex mwe_main` and then `biber mwe_main`. What do yo get?

Comment: Your biber setting seems to be missing the `%.bcf` or `%`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I changed it "/usr/texbin/biber" to "/usr/texbin/biber" %.bcf and it working now :-D thank you so much!

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate, since the answer there addresses this problem here quite well.